# How do you use the error value returned by calcOpticalFlowPyrLK

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am using goodFeaturesToTrack and calcOpticalFlowPyrLK  and I am trying to eliminate poor matches. I would like to use the error that is returned.
The standard format is

```
kp2, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevImg, currImg, prevPts, None, **lk_params)
```

What is the 'err' and how do I interpret it?
I have read that it is the euclidean distance but I am unsure what that means. From where to where?
I can find absolutely no examples using this. Does that mean it is not very useful?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docs say](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga473e4b886d0bcc6b65831eb88ed93323):

> type of the error measure can be set in flags parameter; if the flow wasn't found then the error is not defined (use the status parameter to find such cases).

And

> `OPTFLOW_LK_GET_MIN_EIGENVALS`: use minimum eigenvalues as an error measure (see `minEigThreshold` description); if the flag is not set, then L1 distance between patches around the original and a moved point, divided by number of pixels in a window, is used as a error measure.

So, depends on what flags you pass, or didn't pass. If you did nothing, then you've got an "L1 distance between patches around the original and a moved point [...]"

That's a measure of per-pixel difference. L1 means "straight-up sum" (of absolute differences).

Comment: what does 'L1 distance between patches around the original and a moved point ' mean?

Comment: do you understand what "patches" are in this context? do look up these things before asking a human

Comment: I assume 'patches' refers to the window used by the Lucas Kanade method to calculate the flow. ie the winSize parameter in the goodFeaturesToTrack. But I still do not understand what is being said. Is this the L1 distance between the  discovered point end  the original. That would not seem to be a measure of error

Comment: take a patch around a point. do that for both the input point and its tracked result. compare patches per-pixel. that is is. not a spatial distance. -- "distances" are usual lingo for in image processing and computer vision, applied to all kinds of multidimensional things and the differences between them.

Comment: So the err is a measure of how different the patches are?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: Postscript I have tried using the err by sorting the matches in err order then looking at the top half of the matches and then the bottom half. I can see no descernable difference!

Comment: your question did not contain a [mre] (not even data) but you seem to have an issue that requires looking at data. I won't ask for data now because then I'd be asking you to move the goalposts.